# @multimethod in combination with Protocol = Error

Tags: python

I'm trying to use @multimethod in combination with Protocol. But at runtime I get this error

> TypeError: Protocols with non-method members don't support issubclass()

```
@runtime_checkable
class SenderContext(Protocol):
    @property
    def cancellation_token(self) -> bool:
        ...

    def send(self, target: PID, message: Any) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError("Should Implement this method")


@multimethod
def subscribe(self, msg_type: type,
              context: SenderContext) -> None:
```

How can I fix this error? If I remove the property **cancellation_token**, then everything works fine. But I need a property **cancellation_token**.